# React mui - make menu items sticky to select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, drop-down-menu

How to keep mui MenuItem sticky to Select when scrolling down?

Here codesandbox which presents the issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-knuth-5hr2dg?file=/Demo.tsx

Just click on select and start scrolling down. Menu items will go down when you scroll and I would like them to stay with select. When I scroll down menu items should be going up and eventually disappearing as select does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu items are contained within a dialog element identified by the id `menu-`. The dialog is set to have a `fixed` position, which means it remains visible even when scrolling. To achieve this effect, you can apply the following CSS class instead:

```css
#menu- {
  position: absolute;
}
```